# Deployment failed, MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, deployment, pom.xml

I looked at similar cases and there is a problem in the repository, but I don’t have it in pom.xml, or I don’t understand something

This problem happened when I post my project on heroku and it keeps crashing on deployment

After I tried to deploy the project in maven, but it gave the same error

Info:

```
[INFO] Results:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ Online-shop-managment ---
    [INFO] Building jar: C:\dev\projects\Online-shop-managment\target\Online-shop-managment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.1:repackage (repackage) @ Online-shop-managment ---
    [INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ Online-shop-managment ---
    [INFO] Installing C:\dev\projects\Online-shop-managment\target\Online-shop-managment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\vadiy\.m2\repository\com\example\Online-shop-managment\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Online-shop-managment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] Installing C:\dev\projects\Online-shop-managment\pom.xml to C:\Users\vadiy\.m2\repository\com\example\Online-shop-managment\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Online-shop-managment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ Online-shop-managment ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  46.914 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-02T10:24:43+03:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project Online-shop-managment: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Online-shop-managment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Online-shop-management</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What do you think my problem is ?

Comment: The `maven-deploy-plugin` is used to publish an artifact to a repository (i.e. nexus). The error suggests that you don't have configured one in your `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`.

Comment: The `distributionManagement` is missing in your pom file as the error output shows...